# What is the "metaphysical status" of vacuous truth?

Tags: logic, metaphysics

Consider the set "of objects on the table" and suppose that the table is empty.

Point of view 1: the elements of the set have the same properties the any other real objects on the table

Point of view 2: the elements of the set have the same properties the any other real objects on the table, except existence

Point of view 3: the elements of the set don't have properties

Point of view 4: this set does not exist

Point of view 5: the elements of the set have all properties

Now, in my shallow understanding of vacuous truth, the POV5 is the correct, but this looks so wrong. What was the mistake in my reasoning? How to overcome this seeming contradiction?

Comment: By "metaphysical status" I mean what is the relationship between truth and the logical validity of the vacuous truth?

Comment: Perhaps you can consider a simpler example. Does a non-vacuous set exist? Say, the set {1,2,3}. Does it "exist?" In what sense? Likewise say there's an apple on the table. Is there also a set containing the apple? And a set containing the set containing the apple?

Comment: You need more details or way more clarity to this question. Truth as in what scientific truth where you need experimentation to be convinced? Do you mean objective truth where the truth value does not change ever? Objective truth means true forever & never any false instances. Validity has nothing to do with reality.  Some valid arguments can be nonsensical in reality. Everyone here should tell you valid doesn't mean true in reality. Typically metaphysical means not scientific or scientific reality. That is, no sense verification possible to the topic. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @user4894 the example is simple. There are no objects on the table and I am taking the set of objects on the table. The POV 1, 2 and 4 are just are just to show the problem with assuming POV 5.

Comment: @Logikal Objective truth. I want to know if the vacuous truth is an objective truth. If not, could something be objectively true even if it contradicts the vacuous truth?

Comment: See [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) as it has a rigorous definition in logic and math thus including the usual 1st-order ZFC set theory. Metaphysically it could be interpreted in various ways depending on your school of thoughts. If you belong to the Sextus Empiricus Pyrrhonism school who's famous for his 6 books commonly known as *Against the Professors*, then perhaps you should suspend your judgement of its metaphysical existence or not. Know thyself first...

Comment: Vacuous exists only per truth table. You don't look at something in reality & think "that is a vacous truth!" Even if you could do so it would not be ALL CASES but SOMETIMES. Either way this is not reliable in the real world. You seem to be trying very hard to tie an idea to reality. At best this works sometimes.  Objective truth must be practical in the real world & never change value. Something objective true will never be false even centuries later. We can be mistaken about what we think is objective but if there are counter examples then we know the claim is not objective.

Comment: Btw it's a fundamental concept in the classic 1st-order logic underlying set theory that existence is *not* a property, only in [free logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_logic) it makes sense...

Comment: I see... Thanks y'all very much for the great answers.

Comment: Metaphysically we have *concepts* that may be instantiated or not: if they are, there are *objects* falling under the corresponding concept. *Sets* and *classes* Of set theory are the mathematical counterpart of concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Vacuous truth is not the same as vacuous logic: 1 is not consistent with 2, 3 contradicts 5 and 4 contradicts the original consideration (the empty set does exist, that's precisely the starting point, both statements depend not on vacuity).

Metaphysically, this is a trivial contradiction, not an issue of vacuous truth.

Answer (score 1):

From the mathematical viewpoint point 1,2,3,5 are true, while point 4 is false.

Reason: The set of elements in question is the **empty set**. The set exists, it has **no elements**; according to the definition from set theory. Hence point 4 is false.

If a set has no elements then each element of the set satisfies any condition; according to the mathematical logic of 'ex falso quodlibet'. Hence point 1,2,3,5 are true.

Answer (score 1):

> What was the mistake in my reasoning?

Your mistake is to assume that what you describe as "vacuous truth" has any deep meaning, while in fact it is just a relatively trivial thing, more a definition than any deep reasoning.

It's an edge case for talking about sets; if you ask "Does statement X hold for any element A of set M?"; and if M is the empty set, then mathematicians or logicians *define* the answer to this to be true. "X" can be literally anything and everything you can ever dream up, therefore there is no meaning here.

Doing it this way (instead of, for example, introducing a much more complicated ternary logic based on "true", "false" and "undefined") is just very convenient. It is intuitive, it matches the literal meaning of "for every element", it introduces no contradictions, it is great for inductive proofs in maths, and also transforms nicely to the equivalent classical / boolean logic constructs, where "everything follows from a contradiction", which would be what "vacuous truth" would be normally about when people use the term.